# How to set focus on input field in Vuejs when field loads conditionally with v-if

Tags: vue.js

My form has a first name and last name that initially appear as one compact string, but split into two input fields when the user clicks on the string. I need these two input fields to disappear and revert back to the compact string format when the user clicks elsewhere on the page (anywhere other than inside those two input fields). In order to achieve this, I use a v-on directive with the blur attribute. This works well, but only if the user first clicks into one of the input fields to trigger focus. This is because blur only triggers on an input field that is already in focus. Is there either a way for me to automatically put the first input field in focus when the input element conditionally renders? Is there a better approach?

Cheers.

Here is my HTML:

```
<a v-if="!eitherNameSelected" @click="firstNameSelected"> 
    {{person.firstname}} {{person.lastname}}</a>                            
    <div class="row" v-else-if="eitherNameSelected" v-enter="focusOnFirstChild($event)">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <input
                                    @focus="firstnameselected=true"
                                    @blur="firstnameselected=false"
                                    type="text"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="example-text-input-invalid is-invalid"
                                    id="firstname"
                                    placeholder="First Name"
                                    v-model="person.firstname"
                                    >

                           <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Invalid feedback
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input
                                @focus="lastnameselected=true"
                                @blur="lastnameselected=false"
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                                name="example-text-input-invalid is-invalid"
                                placeholder="Last Name"
                                v-model="person.lastname"
                                >
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Invalid feedback
                                </div>
```

And in my Javascript ...

```
    data() {
            return {
                listid: 0,
                listname: "",
                personid: 0,
                person: {},
                nameselected: false,
                activetab1: "main",
                activetab2: "notes",
                firstnameselected: false,
                lastnameselected: false,

....


methods: {
     firstNameSelected() {
            var elem = vm.$el.getElementById('firstname');
            elem.focus();
            this.firstnameselected="true";
        }  
    },
    computed: {
        eitherNameSelected() {
            return (this.firstnameselected || this.lastnameselected);
        }
        },
```

Comment: Can you please add some code?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution but you could use a `@click($event)` in order to know where you clicked to hide or not the inputs.

[This post about checking event targets](https://gomakethings.com/checking-event-target-selectors-with-event-bubbling-in-vanilla-javascript/) can be a good start I guess.

I also coded a minimal example to help you get through your issue. I hope it will help you.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    person: {
      firstname: 'PersonFirstname',
      lastname: 'PersonLastname'
    },
    showCompactString: true
  },
  methods: {
    onCompactStringClicked() {
      this.showCompactString = false
    },

    // Hide the inputs if a click is triggered outside of them
    onAppClicked(event) {
      // Do nothing if compact string is being shown
      if (this.showCompactString)
        return

      const fistnameInputClickedOn = event.target.matches('#firstname')
      const lastnameInputClickedOn = event.target.matches('#lastname')
      const anyInputClickedOn = fistnameInputClickedOn || lastnameInputClickedOn

      if (!anyInputClickedOn)
        this.showCompactString = true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" @click="onAppClicked($event)">
  <a v-if="showCompactString" @click.stop="onCompactStringClicked">{{person.firstname}} {{person.lastname}}</a>
  <div class="row" v-else>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" v-model="person.firstname">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" v-model="person.lastname">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't hesitate to leave a comment if you have trouble. I'll answer you back as fast as I can.

Answer (score 0):

put an `@click=someFunction` (or computed) on the root element (i.e. the whole body of HTML) and then have that change the text.

Comment: Thanks. With @click=function in the root element, how do I exclude clicks inside of the two input fields from triggering that function? The function should only trigger when a user clicks outside of these fields.